# Converting .rpm file into .deb file using alien in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, conversion, rpm, deb, alien

I have converted an i336 .rpm file into a .deb file in Ubuntu using alien successfully, but I am getting the following error while converting an i586.rpm file of the same application into a .deb file:

```
Unpacking of 'app-1-1.i586.rpm' failed at /usr/share/perl5/Alien/Package/Rpm.pm line 155.
```

I do not know how to resolve this type of issue.

Answer (score 1):

check your file with an archive manager

maybe it was not downloaded correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to install rpm packages on Ubuntu, Linux Mint, or Debian.

Install alien and all the dependencies it needs:

```
# apt-get install alien dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
```

To convert a package from rpm to Debian format:

```
# alien packagen.rpm
```

Finally, install your package!

```
# dpkg -i package.deb
```

For more info, visit: http://namhuy.net/1207/how-to-install-rpm-packages-on-ubuntu-mint-or-debian.html

```
$ alien -h
```

Comment: I think he knows that already (But it's great for people arriving here  and who don't)